# LINQ, Using Include Function

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I am using EF 6 in Visual Studio 2013. I want to get matching records from a Parent table on behalf of foreign key from Child table.
I have following line of code

```
var record = db.ChannelFees.Include(x =>x.SubSource).ToList();
```

Here ChannelFees is the child table in which SubSourceId is foreign key from
SubSource(Parent Table).

Channel Fee Class Looks Like:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class ChannelFee
{
    public virtual SubSource SubSource { get; set; }
    public int SubSource_id { get; set; }
    public double Fee { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

and the SubSource Class

```
using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class SubSource
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string MapName { get; set; }
    }
```

But I am getting the following exception.

> A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'FinancialManagmentModel.ChannelFee' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'SubSource'.

What is wrong with it?

Comment: Yes LINQ to Entitites I have edited the question too.

Comment: Could you send ChannelFee and SubSource classes please? Also the mapping configuration if you are using fluent interface mapping.

Comment: I have updated the question with ChannelFee and SubSource classes @bubi

Comment: I am new to Entity Framework so I actually don't know what else has to be done to get this

Comment: Your question states that you do have two partial classes called `SubSource`! is that typo?

Comment: Sorry that was posted by mistake. I do have two different classes

Comment: Ok, I wrote some code below. You need a navigation property and a configuration to make it work (and also look some more samples :) ).

Answer (score 2):

I think it should be:

```
public virtual ICollection<SubSource> SubSource;
```

Comment: 'The modifier 'virtual' is not valid for this item' Following error is occuring on placing virtual keyword

Answer (score 2):

You could try with this:

```
public partial class ChannelFee
{
    public virtual ICollection<SubSource> SubSource { get; set; } // Just to enable lazy load
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string MapName { get; set; }
}

public partial class SubSource
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string MapName { get; set; }
    public virtual ChannelFee ChannelFee {get; set; } // Navigation property
}
```

And usually I also add a Mapping in the context (you can achieve the same result with configuration attributes)

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<SubSource>().HasRequired(t => t.ChannelFee)
            .WithMany(t => t.SubSource);
}
```

Comment: Where to put the last method (OnModelCreating())?

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way to solve the problem is to *declare a navigation property with the name 'SubSource'.* through Annotations

```
public partial class ChannelFee
{
        [ForeignKey("SubSource_id")]  
        public virtual SubSource SubSource { get; set; }        
        public int SubSource_id { get; set; }     

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue at my own. Actually the EF was not generating navigation property in the Model on the behalf of  Foreign Key Constraint which I created in SQL, that is why error was occuring.
So I simply deleted the Model and added it again. Problem was solved.